# jQuery - add / remove table rows

Tags: jquery, html, row, tablerow

From my selection on the right I dynamically construct (clone) a set of rows to the left. There I also add a REMOVE button. I can't call a jQuery function from that button. Also upon clicking the REMOVE button how can I set the checkbox of the respective row on the right to its previous state (checked). There is all the code below.
Thank you.

Example
    
    
      </script>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#row_remove").click(function() {       
    alert("1");
    });

 $('#tb11 tr')
 .filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)')
 .addClass('selected')
 .end()
  .click(function(event) {
    //alert("1");

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {

            $(':checkbox', this).attr('checked', function() {

                if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                {
                  $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#tbl2").append("<label><input type='text' name='textfield' id='textfield'/></label><button id='row_remove'>remove</button>");

                  //ac 1
                  var findCheckBox = $("#tbl2 input:checkbox.chkclass");
                  findCheckBox.remove();

                }
                else
                {
                  var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
                  var findRow = $("#tbl2 tr[id='" + index + "']");
                  findRow.remove();
                }

            return !this.checked;

            });
        }
  });

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

table {
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    text-align: left;
}
.right {
    text-align: left;
}

  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="32%" rowspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#EAEAEA">

    <table width="100%" border="0">

      <tr id="tbl2" width="100%">
       <!-- <td height="101" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="right">&nbsp;</td>-->
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="1%" bgcolor="#EAEAEA">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="67%" colspan="3" rowspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#EAEAEA">

    <table id="tb11" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1">
        <td width="5%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox"  class="chkclass"  value="yes" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td width="95%" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="right">item 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2">
        <td width="5%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox"  class="chkclass"  value="yes" checked="checked"  /></td>
        <td width="95%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="right">item 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="3">
        <td width="5%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox"  class="chkclass"  value="yes" checked="checked"  /></td>
        <td width="95%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="right">item 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="4">
        <td width="5%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox"  class="chkclass"  value="yes"  checked="checked" /></td>
        <td width="95%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="right">item 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="5">
        <td width="5%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox"  class="chkclass"  value="yes" checked="checked"  /></td>
        <td width="95%" height="20" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="right">item 5</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element ID attribute value must be unique!!! Remember this forever!

Check out [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) docs. This method has optional parameter "withDataAndEvents" which is false by default.